# An equivalent form of the definition of conditional probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

Problem: Suppose that the $\sigma$ algebra $\mathscr{G}$ is generated by a $\pi$ system $\mathscr{C}$. Please prove that $f\in\mathscr{G}$ is the conditional probability of the event $A$ with respect to $\mathscr{G}$ if and only if 
$$\int_B f d\mathbb{P}=\mathbb{P}(A\cap B),\forall B\in\mathscr{C}.$$

I believe the necessity is obvious. For the sufficiency of the proof, notice that $\mathscr{C}$ is a $\pi$ system,  the way I think of it is to take
$$\Lambda=\{B\in\mathscr{G}:\int_B f d\mathbb{P}=\mathbb{P}(A\cap B)\}.$$
Then $\mathscr{C}\subset\Lambda$ and if $\Lambda$ is proved to be a $\lambda$ system, then by monotone class theorem the problem is solved. Is easy to check if $B,C\in\Lambda$ and $C\subset B$, then $B-C\in\Lambda$. And is also easy to check if $A_n\in\Lambda,n=1,2,\cdots$ and $A_n\uparrow B$, then $A\in\Lambda$. But I don't know how to prove that the whole space $\Omega \in \Lambda$.
Please give me some ideas, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not true. Suppose $\Omega = \{\omega_1, \omega_2\}$, $\mathscr C = \{\{\omega_1\}\}$, and $\mathscr G$ contains every subset of $\Omega$. Let $\mathbb P\{\omega_1\}=0$, $A = \{\omega_2\}$, and $f=2$. Then,
$$\int_{\{\omega_1\}}fd\mathbb P = 0 = \mathbb P(A \cap \{\omega_1\}).$$
But 
$$\int_\Omega f d\mathbb P = 2 \neq 1 = \mathbb P(A \cap \Omega).$$
In practice, the generating set $\mathscr C$ is often an algebra (and therefore contains $\Omega$) or is easily seen to contain $\Omega$, in which case the result goes through using the proof you sketched.

Comment: Your answer is very helpful! Thank you!